# How to calculate the sum of nodes grouped per units in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to calculate the sum of XML values based on a node in XML with XSLT1.0.
I would need the sum of all `@Qty` values that are available in Routes table. Each `OrderTrans` from Routes has an `itedID`, that will match the `itemID` from Products. The Products table also has the `ItemDetails` node, and each product will have a `unitID`. My final result should show the sum of all `@Qty` grouped by `@unitID`.

Below is the XML source:

```
<root>
    <Routes>
        <OrderTrans itemID="1">
            <View Qty="5.00"/>
        </OrderTrans>
        <OrderTrans itemID="2">
            <View Qty="200.00"/>
        </OrderTrans>
        <OrderTrans itemID="2">
            <View Qty="10.00"/>
        </OrderTrans>
        <OrderTrans itemID="1">
            <View Qty="20.00"/>
        </OrderTrans>
    </Routes>
    <Products>
        <Product itemID="2">
            <ItemDetails unitID="KG"/>
        </Product>
        <Product itemID="1">
            <ItemDetails unitID="Pcs"/>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</root>
```

Here is a snippet of what I tried:

```
<xsl:key name="groupkey" match="/root/Products/Product/ItemDetails" use="@unitID"/>
<xsl:template>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/Products/Product/ItemDetails[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupkey',@unitID)[1])]">
        <fo:block>Sum here:
            <xsl:value select="sum(../../../Routes/OrderTrans/View/@Qty[@unitID = current()/@unitID])">
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xslt:template>
```

The result should be:

```
Sum here: 25.00 Pcs. 210.00 KG
```

Comment: Your code is full of errors, which makes it unusable for those of us who would want to use it to solve your problem. Please show more consideration for the time of people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to group anything, when you already have a unique node for each Product. You can do simply:

```
<xsl:key name="order" match="OrderTrans" use="@itemID"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <your-root-here>
        <xsl:for-each select="Products/Product">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:text>Sum here: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('order', @itemID)/View/@Qty)"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="ItemDetails/@unitID"/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </your-root-here>
</xsl:template>
```